# RStudio Project creation on Windows network share issue

Tags: r, rstudio

RStudio 1.2.5033 and 1.3.1073 is crashing when creating standard New projects (although not with R package projects) on "some" Windows Network Share Drives.

Comment: Putting this here so others that run into this issue can potentially also find an answer to this problem on SO. Adding links to github ticket, root cause and solution as answer.

Comment: This also seems to effect knitting functionality - when knitting on network shares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of current (ie Sept. 2020) this is supposed to get fixed with RStudio's next boost update see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63738420/1216790 for similar or root cause of issue
and
https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/7716#issuecomment-686641326 regarding expected solution.